# Create multi line byte string in Python 3.7

Tags: python, sockets

How to create a multiline byte string in Python? I want to send multiline string in Python 3.7 using

```
socket.send()
```

I tried following,

> Case 1

```
strng = """foo
bar"""

byte_str = strng.encode()
```

When I print byte_str, output is

```
"foo\nbar"
```

> Case 2

```
byte_str = b"""foo
bar"""
```

When I print byte_str, output is

```
"foo\nbar"
```

In both cases new line is being replaced with '\n'.

Comment: Why do you expect a byte string to know anything about lines?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I want to send multiline text using sockets. Is there any way?

Comment: "new line is being replaced with '\n' " A new line _is_ `'\n'`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I know '\n' is whitespace character for new line. If you print it as string you won't see '\n' in output, you will only see a newline which is not the case with bytestring. Try to understand context.

Comment: By the way, for coding one string on multiple lines without adding line feed sequence, you could write `strng = """foo \ `, next line: `bar"""`

Answer (score 0):

bytecode are not aware of special meaning of newline `\n`. You can take a string (`s`) with new lines (as you have done). Convert it to bytecode (`bs`) and send across. Receive it at the other end and decode (`ss = bs.decode()`). The expression `s == ss` should be `True`. On the consolde both `print(s)` and `print(ss)` should reproduce the new line.